# Order by case statement that extracts substring from column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below SQL that takes only data from the Name column up to the point where a space or hyphen appears. I would like to order the results by the output of the case statement but can't find a way to do it.

```sql
select 

case 
when strpos("Name",' ') > 0 then substr("Name", 0, strpos("Name", ' '))
when strpos("Name",'-') > 0 then substr("Name", 0, strpos("Name", '-'))
else "Name"
end as StrippedName

from myTable

order by "StrippedName"
```

Comment: You'll have to use a subquery or CTE. The query will be very slow in either case because the database won't be able to use any indexes that cover `Name`. You could eliminate `CASE` by using `regexp_split_to_array`, eg `regexp_split_to_array(name,'[ -]')[1]`. This will reduce the code but still can't use indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  case ... end as col1
        from    ...
        ) as SubQueryAlias
order by
        col1
```

Comment: I tried that approach but I get "ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: Sounds like you're using a subquery as a column in the `select` list.  What happens when you use it as shown above, in the `from` section of the query?

Comment: Ah I see, you're correct that works, however I am trying to include a count(*) from the main table and hence why I have multiple rows returned from the subquery

Comment: @Andomar Neither a CTE nor a subquery as a `from` or `select` item is necessary - OP just missed one pair of double-quotes. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77727369/5298879).

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is perfectly fine as long as you double-quote the name of the `case` result in ***both*** the `select` list ***and*** the `order by`. Mismatching the quotes makes the `case` produce a column named `strippedname`, while `order by` looks for a
`StrippedName` and doesn't find it, throwing an

> ```
> ERROR:  column "StrippedName" does not exist
> LINE 9: order by "StrippedName";
>                  ^
> ```

If you drop the quotes in both places or use them in both, it'll work just fine: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8c6qRMy1)

```
create table myTable ("Name" text);
insert into myTable values ('2abc-def'),('3abcdef'),('1abc def')

select case 
         when strpos("Name",' ') > 0 
           then substr("Name", 0, strpos("Name", ' '))
         when strpos("Name",'-') > 0 
           then substr("Name", 0, strpos("Name", '-'))
         else "Name"
       end as "StrippedName" --without " it was folded to "strippedname"
from myTable
order by "StrippedName"--was looking for a case-sensitive "StrippedName"
--order by 1 --you could also pick a column by its position
```

| StrippedName |
| --- |
| 1abc |
| 2abc |
| 3abcdef |

A reminder from the doc on [PostgreSQL lexical structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case.

You can also use a column position instead of its name: [`order by 1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> Each expression can be the name **or ordinal number** of an output column (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values.

---

It's [possible](https://dbfiddle.uk/UdJWDU1g) to reduce your entire `case` down to a single [substring](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.27.1.1.1) with a [POSIX regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```sql
select regexp_substr("Name",'([^ -]+)') as "StrippedName"
from myTable 
order by "StrippedName"
```

It's looking for a sequence of characters that aren't a hyphen `-` or a space  , so it'll return everything up to the first position of either (or the whole thing if neither is found). Using a `+` rather than a `*` makes it skip leading delimiters, looking for non-empty matches.

Comment: Didn't know quoting an identifier makes it case-sensitive, cheers!